# spring security - Home page setup for authorize and unauthorize user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

i'm stuck in spring security configuration. can any one help me for better solution. i have 2 jsp page one for login user and other for simple user. in which login user have option for logout and while in other jsp have option for login and signup.

my secuirty configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${winni.auth.exit}")
    private String authExit;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login","/web/**" ,"/exit","/action/**","/cart/**","/cart/xhr/**","/buyer/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll().and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl(authExit);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**","/account/**","/start/**");
    }
}
```

home controller is

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(Principal principal) {
        if (principal != null) {
            return "login_user";
        } else {
            return "simple_user";
        }

    }
```

in every case Principal Object also null. how can solve this issue.

Comment: May be you need to configure some filters and @EnableWebMvc annotation is missing i guess. I am not though, possibly you might need to give a little thought in that direction.

Comment: @EnableWebMvc  doesn't work for me.